# rails 4 will_paginate set count of links on pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, will-paginate

I'm using rails 4 and gem will_paginate. I can't customize count of links on pages before gap (...). eg now I having 9 pages than ellipsis and 3 last pages. How can I set 5 pages instead 9 (see scrennshots)?
In controller:

```
 @per_page = params[:per_page] || 6
 @events = Event.not_cancelled.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => @per_page)
```

Now

[image]

That I want

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must change value for `inner_window`. Reference [here](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/API-documentation).

So here is code:

```
<%= will_paginate @events, :inner_window => 2, :outer_window => 1 %>
```